# Known issues when installing official google ICS on Galaxy s2

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-s-2, rom

I know Google issued out an official ICS rom for the Nexus S devices and I'm wandering if the same rom (or any other Google official variant) will properly work on my Galaxy S2 or will there be any notable issues?!

I'm asking because I'm quite fed up with the Samsung's stock roms (both GB and ICS) and I really want to avoid 3rd party roms such as CyanogenMod.

Comment: It's probably not too hard to adapt for example the CyanogenMod build procedures for the S2 to use plain Google sources, but I haven't tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, that's not how it works :/

Though we would all love the official ICS versions rolled out to the Nexus S and Galaxy Nexus devices, they are designed specifically for the hardware of those phones; thus is the nature of Android.

So, if you want something similar, the only way you will be able to get it is a 3rd party ROM. The **only** official OS versions for each phone are the ones rolled out by each provider, in your case, Samsung.

Comment: I was afraid of that, Samsung do roll out nice devices, but they stuff so much garbage and bloatware in them it's painful.

Comment: If you like Samsung hardware, I'd recommend getting one of the aforementioned phones (Nexus S, Galaxy Nexus) if you're getting a new one soon. They are Google's brainchildren, but Samsung produces them.

Comment: In the end I've found a rom for the S2 compiled from the source code FOR THE Nexus S and it works like a charm :) http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1601518